# How to create single/multiple number ranges from continuous but broken small ranges in oracle

Tags: oracle, numbers, range, grouping

How to create single/multiple number ranges from continuous but broken small ranges in oracle

I have following data set in one table

| main Product | Sub Product | Start Serial | End Serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Main01 | sub01 | 166255 | 166258 |
| Main01 | sub02 | 666255 | 666258 |
| Main02 | sub01 | 166259 | 166262 |
| Main02 | sub02 | 666259 | 666262 |
| Main03 | sub01 | 166267 | 166270 |
| Main03 | sub02 | 666267 | 666270 |

and need to create summarized ranges as below

| Sub Product | Start Serial | End Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub01 | 166255 | 166262 |
| sub02 | 666255 | 666262 |
| sub01 | 166267 | 166270 |
| sub02 | 666267 | 666270 |

Comment: What's the purpose of keeping mainProduct if it's not related to the ranges you're building? Probably this post first needs more clarity on how you're matching ranges...

Comment: Please clarify your requirement: provide the rules in general words to obtain this result from the input provided. And post your current code to see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT main_product,
       sub_product,
       start_serial,
       end_serial
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY sub_product
  ORDER BY start_serial
  MEASURES
    FIRST(main_product) AS main_product,
    FIRST(start_serial) AS start_serial,
    MAX(end_serial) AS end_serial
  PATTERN (overlaps* last_row)
  DEFINE
    overlaps AS MAX(end_serial) + 1 >= NEXT(start_serial)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Main_Product, Sub_Product, Start_Serial, End_Serial) AS
SELECT 'Main01', 'sub01', 166255, 166258 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main01', 'sub02', 666255, 666258 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main02', 'sub01', 166259, 166262 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main02', 'sub02', 666259, 666262 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main03', 'sub01', 166267, 166270 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Main03', 'sub02', 666267, 666270 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MAIN_PRODUCT | SUB_PRODUCT | START_SERIAL | END_SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Main01 | sub01 | 166255 | 166262 |
| Main03 | sub01 | 166267 | 166270 |
| Main01 | sub02 | 666255 | 666262 |
| Main03 | sub02 | 666267 | 666270 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hRxedFgL)